# VS Code Suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I've noticed that whenever I try to use a method i.e .push(), .toLowerCase(), etc. it does not show up as a suggestions, when I start typing it. Is there a setting I can enable to activate the suggestion for this?

Thank in advance!

I've searched everywhere and still can't find an answer. I tried the following as well:

```
"editor.suggest.showFunctions": true,
    "editor.suggest.showSnippets": true, 
    "editor.suggest.showMethods": true,
```

Comment: What does your `Editor: Quick Suggestions` setting look like?

Comment: do you mean this, it's my default:

    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "on",
        "comments": "off",
        "strings": "off",
    },